# How can I disable a single phone connector?

Tags: audio, connector

I have two phone connectors on my laptop. One regular 3.5mm audio connector and a 3mm subwoofer connector.

Recently,  the subwoofer I got with the computer fell off the table and broke a part of the jack off inside the port. The port is fairly mangled so I opened my laptop but can't get to the connector without having thermal paste to reapply to my CPU. I originally tried to just disable the subwoofer port so it wouldn't be distorting my audio but I couldn't find anything. I don't want to deal with fixing it at the moment, so I'm back to trying that.

It seems to show up in my Realtek HD audio manager under my other connector and allows me to turn it down but not disable it. I've googled it extensively but nothing's coming up. Any ideas?

OS: Windows 8.1

Model: Asus N550L

Comment: Can you reassign it to some input?

Comment: You could try supergluing something  (toothpick? cut it for a flat end) to the broken-off piece to pull it out. Make sure glue doesn't get on the port or other parts (use a tiny bit and hold it there to set). 5-minute epoxy works too.

Comment: No can do, @Bob. I tried that with the plastic tube from a cotton swab but was too impatient and pulled it out too soon. I think there's a small bit of glue stuck to the plastic part of the port now. Either way, that and the already mangled state of the port makes me not want to mess around with it any more.

Comment: I've tried that a few ways, @gronostaj, but no place seems to recognise it as being distinct from the audio port. [Examples](http://imgur.com/a/8PRPq). Do you mean using Device Manager?